# Which grows faster $n^{\log(\log n)}$ or $(\log n)^{\log n}$

Tags: asymptotics

I usually just try playing around with properties of log, but it doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Hint: apply $10^{\log(x)}$ to both expressions

Comment: i tried but couldn't get them into a comparable form

Comment: I tried to edit this to improve the format in the title, but I'm afraid I may have accidentally changed the meaning.  Please check.

Answer (score 2):

they are the same...............really...

Comment: @Alzebrian Not just similar -- the same.

Answer (score 2):

Take the log of each and apply $\log(x^y) = y \log x$ to obtain
$$\log \left(n^{\log(\log n)}\right) = \log(\log n) \log n$$
and
$$\log \left((\log n)^{\log n}\right) = \log n \log(\log n).$$
Because $\log$ is monotonic, the original expressions are also equal to each other.

Comment: I don't understand step 2. It's is essentially saying log(log (n^2)) = 2 log(log n). Is that correct ?

Comment: No, but $\log((\log n)^2)=2\log(\log n)$.